# JDBC INSERT not working

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am just trying to insert a new row in a table from a java application to an SQL database. I have used the same code before and it worked but for some reasons this doesn't. I have checked my query by inserting it directly in phpmyadmin and it works. Here is my code:

where I actually try to sent the query:

```
static Connection conn = MySQLAccess.connectDB();
static PreparedStatement pst = null;
static ResultSet rs = null;

public static String submit(String usrn, String psw){
    String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_user VALUES('', '"+usrn+"', '"+psw+"')";

    try {
       pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
       System.out.println(sql);
       rs=pst.executeQuery();

       if (rs.next()){
           return "ok";
       } else {
           return "fail";
       }
    } catch (Exception e){
        return "fail_connection";
    }
}
```

MySQLAccess.java (which I am sure works because I use is at other points in the code):

```
public class MySQLAccess {
    Connection conn=null;
    public static Connection connectDB (){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/g52gui","root","");
            return conn;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

I have just changed my code (suggestion of Luiggi Mendoza) but no result:

```
public static String submit(String usrn, String psw){
        //String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_user VALUES('', '"+usrn+"', '"+psw+"')";
        String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_user VALUES('', '?', '?')";
        String result = "failed";
        try (Connection conn = MySQLAccess.connectDB();
             PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            pst.setString(1, usrn);
            pst.setString(2, psw);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            result = "worked";
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //handle your exception...
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You're using `PreparedStatement#executeQuery` when you should use `PreparedStatement#executeUpdate`.

Comment: Your SQL Query is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please use PreparedStatement.

Comment: It seems to error at the  pst.setString(1, usrn); pst.setString(2, psw); I tried to system.out something after these 2 line but nothing came up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three issues:

1. Use `PreparedStatement#executeUpdate` rather than `PreparedStatement#executeQuery`.
2. Keep the variables in the narrowest possible scope. Don't set them as `static` variables in your class.
3. Don't concatenate the parameters into the query string. Instead, use `PreparedStatement#setXyz` method to set the proper parameter.

Gluing all of these together produces the following code:

```
public static String submit(String usrn, String psw){
    //String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_user VALUES('', '"+usrn+"', '"+psw+"')";
    String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_user VALUES('', ?, ?)";
    String result = "failed";
    try (Connection conn = MySQLAccess.connectDB();
         PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        pst.setString(1, usrn);
        pst.setString(2, psw);
        pst.executeUpdate();
        result = "worked";
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //handle your exception...
    }
    return result;
}
```

---

From your new code, the  problem is here:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_user VALUES('', '?', '?')";
                                              ^ ^  ^ ^
```

You're wrapping the parameter character `?` with quotes `'`. Remove such quotes, as shown in my code:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_user VALUES('', ?, ?)";
//No quotes around ?
```

Comment: It seems to error at the pst.setString(1, usrn); pst.setString(2, psw); I tried to system.out something after these 2 line but nothing came up.

Comment: Did you handle the exception at least by using `e.printStackTrace()`? What's your new *problem* now?

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0). I guess there is something wrong in the preparedStatement, I also tried to change 1 to 0 and 2 to 1 but no success

Comment: Ok it seems to work however i get this error: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'usr_id' at row 1
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:946)  I know that it is because I am trying to insert the wrong value but the 'usr_id' in my database is an auto-increment number how should I deal with this ?

Comment: @Rémi if the column is numeric and supports `AUTO_INCREMENT` then insert `NULL` (not `'NULL'`, they're different!) in it, the database will generate the new value for you.

Comment: Ok thank you very much it seems to be all working fine ! Really appreciate your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use executeUpdate and not executeQuery;